# How to check a condition and add to list in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to define a predicate where given a list "C" and budget "B", it will check the items in the list and output a list "I" that can be purchased given the budget.

I have defined the below relations for the cost of each item.

```
cost(phone,1500)
cost(tablet,1300)
cost(headphones,200)
cost(powerbank, 120)
```

Here is how I defined the predicate

```
catalogue_budget([], B, []) %base case - in case an empty list is inputted
catalogue_budget([Head|Tail],B,I):-
    cost(Head,price) %getting the price of the item
```

I am struggling in implementing the condition check and adding the item to the list "I" to be returned

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do so, since it is quite an easy task:

```
can_buy([],_,[]).
can_buy([Item|T],Budget,[Item|To]):-
    cost(Item,C),
    C =< Budget,
    can_buy(T,Budget,To).
can_buy([Item|T],Budget,To):-
    cost(Item,C),
    C > Budget,
    can_buy(T,Budget,To).
?- can_buy([phone,tablet],1300,C).
C = [tablet]
false
```

or even more compactly, with SWI Prolog

```
enough(B,El):-
    cost(El,C),
    C =< B.

?- include(enough(1300),[phone,tablet],R).
R = [tablet]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however the list returned contains the different items that can be bought, but what I'm looking for is the sum of the returned list to be less than or equal to Budget. For example if accessory and case both cost 400 and budget is 400 then the list returned should contain one item but not both.